# MS Access 2000 Chart

Tags: ms-access, charts

I'm completely new in MS Access. So I need to add a chart with points, connected with lines. Also I need to draw 2 horizontal lines: 1 for Max result of the graph, 1 for Min result of the graph.
After some investigation I found out that I can draw graph using pivot request. In this case I will have chart with points. But how can I draw 2 more lines on the graph?
The best solution will be to add each point using VBA. But after an hour of googling I have not found any example of such code. Maybe I'm adding incorrect Chart? I open Form, click Insert -> Chart.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would probably to be create 2 new fields in whatever table you're using to create the chart. You can set those values in an Update query... something along the lines of:

```
sql = "UPDATE tblChart Set tblChart.[yourMaxField] = dMAX(""DataSeries"", ""tblChart""), tblChart.[yourMinField] = dMIN(""DataSeries"", ""tblChart"")
DoCmd.runsql sql
```

Then you would just add yourMaxField and yourMinField to the chart as data elements, and set their style to "Line".

Comment: I can't modify tables structure. Is it possible to add points to graph using VBA? Something like - msCart.Items.Add(...)?